# I accidentally disabled execution of all files on my OS

Tags: debian, chmod

`sudo chmod -333 /`
The system expectedly doesn't work. I'm wondering if there are any ways to get it back up besides reinstallation?

My operating system is Debian.

Comment: Have you tried entering with the root account and then chmodding it back to what it was? Also, did you recurse it? If you did, you might have to do a reinstall.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by 'entering with the root account'. My OS can only boot in restore mode, otherwise it gets stuck on boot. Regarding recursing, command was executed as described in the question, so possibly it wasn't recursive.

Comment: The correct mode for the root folder is 755. If you're able to boot into single user mode and perform `chmod 755 /` (or whatever the path is to the ordinary system's root directory once in single-user mode), that would likely fix it.  As you have not mentioned what Unix you're using, I can't say that this is a real answer as a real answer would likely also let you know how to access single user mode.

Comment: May we ask which OS actually is "Your OS"?

Comment: @gerhardd. The system in question is Debian. Sorry for not specifying earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the actual command that you used, then it didn't actually operate on all of the files on the system as the `-R` or recursive switch wasn't used. You basically just removed write and execute permissions for the user, group, and everyone of the `/` or root directory (not to be confused with `/root` which is the home directory of the `root` user.

You would have had to be `root` in order for that command to work. You could have simply run `chmod 755 /` as root which would have restored it to what it was.

Depending on what Unix-based OS, you are using, if you can get into rescue mode or single-user mode, then you can run the above command from there from most Linux distributions; however, there are others where this may not be possible. Via Google, there are walk-throughs on entering single user mode for every operating system where it is available. If that method doesn't work, then it's possible that you'll have to reinstall.

Comment: Note that depending on what "rescue mode" means with their Unix, the ordinary root directory may (or may not) be mounted as a sub-directory of some RAM disk file system.

Comment: The OS is Debian. chmod run as root from single user mode fails with Read-only filesystem.

Comment: In recovery mode it doesn't fail, but doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Trashbin2019np In single-user mode, you need to mount the system as read-write. The instructions from any tutorial will show you how to do this.